# Accept POST requests from external domain? (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tornado, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I can't seem to get my app to accept POST requests from a different domain. I'm trying to make an PayPal IPN handler in my app.

When a user clicks the "Subscribe" button on my page, PayPal sends an IPN (a POST), to my IPN handler.

I can see in my AppEngine logs that a POST request is received, but it is empty (e.g. no arguments, my logging.debug messages aren't showing up in the logs, etc.)

So I test my handler by making a POST to it *within* my app, and the handler works as expected.

I'm assuming it's a security feature to not accept POSTs from outside sources? If so, how do I make my app accept POSTs from PayPal?

Here's what my handler looks like at the moment (it's just for testing):

```
class BaseHandler(tornadotoad.mixin.RequestHandler, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    # ...

class IPNHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        if is_ajax(self.request):
            logging.info('AJAX')
        logging.info(self.request.arguments)
        self.write("This is the IPN Handler\n'")
        self.write(self.request.arguments)
        return
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using PayPal's [Sandbox Test Tool](https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr) to send the IPN

Comment: There's no security issue that I know of that would prevent this. Are you sure the request from PayPal actually contains the data you want?

Comment: No, there's no 'security feature'. What is `is_ajax`? What status code does your handler return? Are you sure you're using the right URL and your handler is being called at all? Can you show us a simple demo app that exhibits the problem, and a command line (curl/wget) that demonstrates it?

Comment: How are you making sure that post is coming from PayPal. Also, could you tell which integration model with PayPay you are trying?

Comment: @NickJohnson is_ajax is just a function which checks the request's headers if it contains 'XMLHttpRequest'. I *think* my handler is being called, since I get this `2012-04-27 11:13:50.294 /ipn 302 23ms 0kb
173.0.82.126 - - [26/Apr/2012:20:13:50 -0700] "POST /ipn HTTP/1.1" 302 0 - - "myapp.appspot.com" ms=23 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000108 ` in my logs when sending the IPN.

Comment: @KarthikAnanth I'm using the [Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_wp_standard_overview) methods.

Comment: @john2x The header line indicates you're sending a 302 in response to the request. Why that is depends on your code - perhaps you're requiring login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake. I put the url for the handler together with the other urls, which has `login: required` in `app.yaml`.

I've fixed this and now PayPal's IPN is getting through.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You may and should accept your own answer. It'll help the next viewer.

Answer (score 1):

A few hunches here.

1. Maybe "/ipn" is not being routed to IPNHandler. Perhaps another deprecated handler?
2. Maybe the app version you are looking at in your logs is not the same as the one you have. Perhaps you can deploy a new version of your code and test against the new one.
3. Maybe the POST request Paypal is sending you has no arguments.

P.S. More info on how you are performing tests from Paypal's end, showing other relevant parts of your code, and any other relevant info could help. :)

Comment: I'm using PayPal's [IPN test tool](https://developer.paypal.com/devscr?cmd=_tools-session) to simulate sending an IPN. (You'll need to register a dummy account at http://developer.paypal.com). Once in the tool, enter `http://wmp-ipn-handler-test.appspot.com/ipn` in the **IPN Handler URL** and click "Send". To test if `/ipn` is working, go [here](http://wmp-ipn-handler-test.appspot.com/subscribe) and there will be a form which POSTs to /ipn as well.

Comment: Your link to your app subscription gives me a "Server Error".

Comment: I just tested your /ipn by sending it post requests. It seems to work fine. There is NO "security feature" that is stopping requests from Paypal. Look at the way you are using Paypal's IPN Simulator. There might be something amiss there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, and I might be way out of my league here but for tornado I don't seem to be able to find either a method or an attribute of that name in the [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=request#tornado.web.RequestHandler)...

At least for webapp I believe `arguments` is an instance method:

```
 logging.info(self.request.arguments())
```

see the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_arguments).

Comment: I'm using Tornado on GAE, where `arguments` is a dict.

Comment: Excuse the misdirection. I just glanced over my code (webapp-based) which does exactly what you want to do and I do get all my arguments back (using the IPN simulator...). So in response to your question whether it is a security issue; that is a definite no.